# startx over ssh, output to hdmi

Tags: ssh, hdmi

I use the Raspian Wheezy image on my Pi and I'm facing a small problem regarding the hdmi-output. Usually, I have to "plug in" the hdmi-cable (4:1 hdmi switch) and then the Pi to get a video signal to the TV.

Is there a possibility to start the desktop from ssh when the to cable is plugged in after the Pi's boot?

Just to point this out, I'm not looking for a desktop-client like VNC or xrdp, I'm just searching for a solution to fix my problem. What I already tried:

```
# export DISPLAY=:0.0
# startx
```

which resulted in

```
FATAL: Module g2d_23 not found.
```

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking. Do you want to use hdmi, even if not initially connected? I can think of at least 3 other interpretations of your question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to point out. I want to boot up my Pi, plug in the hdmi and then start the desktop-server from remote.

Comment: Editing my config.txt did change it to the required behaviour. If you could answer my question with this link or close it as a duplicate, I would accept it as the correct answer for future searches.